# Changing image location with differently-sized screens WITHOUT @media

Tags: html, image, css-float, sitefinity

Thanks for the great answers last time, I had been working on that problem for days, and someone solved it in ten minutes. Amazing!! So now I have another question for this talented community!

I'm using Sitefinity for this project; long story short, I don't even know where to access the CSS file, and accessing it would probably break the site (as my boss tells me). So everything has to be done with inline styling.

Here's the setup: there's a bunch of text (in a ul), and an image. The text wraps around the image, which is small enough that the text is squished to the left at first, then continues in its full width underneath.

When the screen gets too small, the text starts wrapping around the image (which has been floated right) in weird ways; one long word can make the text stop and start again after the picture (I've already suggested adding word-break for this, but it's a no-go).

Here's what my boss wants: image floats to the right of the text on larger screens, then floats above and center on smaller screens. Again, no stylesheet, just inline styling.

Some attempted ideas:

- Use asides: can't. That needs the stylesheet. (Unless someone who knows this knows a better way!)
- Use padding on the image: tried. It messes up the formatting; what works to push everything underneath on mobile squishes everything to the side on desktop. (If someone knows a better way, let me know!)
- Use JS: can't. Basically, everything has been styled somewhere deep within the code, so I've just got a tiny HTML text box to work with, no  tag to work with at all.

Thank you for all suggestions! This is a talented community!!

Comment: I'm not convinced what you're asking for can be achieved. The obvious solution would be to use media queries. But without access to the stylesheet.. Can't do them. Throw in no JS and you might find yourself struggling. I cross my fingers for you and hope that someone else proves me wrong.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking!! I can fudge it in some ways, but it's not going to  look as good as if it had queries.

Comment: But for anyone who might need this solution in the future: this can be sorta-solved by using huge margins for the image, and then tying words together with &nbsp; until they automatically go below the image. This causes problems with centering, and the success varies with the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should us a CSS widget, add some classes to your  then within the CSS widget write the appropriate media queries, if you need this to affect more than one page put the CSS widget on a template instead of an individual page.

[image: Widget in toolbox]

[image: Widget in edit mode]